# In which pastiche of Sherlock Holmes does Watson end up being Moriarty?

Tags: identification-request, sherlock-holmes

I read a  pastiche of Sherlock Holmes some time ago that ended up with Watson actually being Moriarty, fooling Holmes all those years, working his machinations under his nose.

Sadly, I can't remember the name of the book, and can't find it by googling...

What was this book?

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Is there any more detail you remember about this story - e.g. when/where did you read it, how long was it, etc? Any little detail might help someone identify it. There's a useful list in the [tag wiki info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: hey! I read it about 2 years ago, and I have the feeling that it was published in the last 8 years... The reveal doesn't happen until the end of the book, basically the last chapter.